# Fill a multidimentional arrays with none existing values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Well basically I have this array `$sales` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orderCount] => 3
            [products] => 4
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => 11
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [orderCount] => 1
            [products] => 2
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => 12
        )
)
```

I would like to fill to complete unexisted months with this array `$months`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Janv
    [2] => Fév
    [3] => Mars
    [4] => Avr
    [5] => Mai
    [6] => Juin
    [7] => Juil
    [8] => Aout
    [9] => Sept
    [10] => Oct
    [11] => Nov
    [12] => Déc
)
```

In a way to generate an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orderCount] => 0
            [products] => 0
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => Janv
      )
      .
      .
    [10] => Array
        (
            [orderCount] => 3
            [products] => 4
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => Nov
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [orderCount] => 1
            [products] => 2
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => Déc
        )
)
```

And here's what've tried so far and didn't work :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($month as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($sales as $k => $v) {
        if( $v['month']==$key){
            $result[] = array(
                "orderCount" => $v['orderCount'],
                "products" => $v['products'],
                "month" => $value,
                "year" => $v['year']
                );
        }else{
            $result[] = array(
                "orderCount" => "0",
                "products" => "0",
                "month" => $value,
                "year" => $v['year']
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want all month in array

Comment: Yea actually I want all the months in the array with names instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

T threw a few things together at this [Demo](http://ideone.com/9Bimw1).

The essence is basically this:

```
$new = array_map(function($row) use($month) {
    $row['month'] = $month[$row['month']];
    return $row;
}, $sales);
```

it iterates the $sales array and "fixes" each month by looking up its int value as index in $months and returning a modified array.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
$aa = array(
array("orderCount"=>3,"products"=>4,"year"=>2014,"month"=>0),
array("orderCount"=>3,"products"=>4,"year"=>2014,"month"=>1),
);

$bb=array("jan","Fév");
foreach($aa as $key=>$val)
{
$month= $val['month'];
$aa[$key]['month']=$bb[$month];
}
print_r($aa);
```

**result:**

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [orderCount] => 3 [products] => 4 [year] => 2014 [month] => jan ) [1] => Array ( [orderCount] => 3 [products] => 4 [year] => 2014 [month] => FÃ©v ) )
```